# How to copy levels of a factor into separate data frames (R)?

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I have a column in a data set for wards of a city. I want to separate these into new and separate data frames for each ward. So, there are 21 or so wards and therefore 21 different levels.

It's important to make it clear that I also want to keep all the data in the MAIN dataframe. Essentially I just want to copy the data of a specific level into its own new data frame so it's represented in both.

I don't know how exactly to make a sample of my big real life data frame, so maybe illustrate a method using this little bit:

```
vector1 <- c(1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 5, 8)
vector2 <- c("ward1", "ward2", "ward2", "ward1", "ward3", "ward2", "ward2", "ward3")
dataframe <- data.frame(vector1, vector2)
dataframe$vector2 <- as.factor(dataframe$vector2)
```

Comment: `split(dataframe, dataframe$vector2)`

Comment: Or `by(dataframe, dataframe$vector2, identity)`